# Python, Pygame, and collision detection efficiency

Tags: python, vector, pygame

I'm making a top-down side-scrolling tile game with a custom sprite class (**not pygame.Sprite**).

The sprite collide() function is causing the frame rate to drop (I used `cProfile`).

Please help me identify the problem.

The function operates in this general manner:

```
def collide(self):
        for tile in tiles:
            if tile.type == 'wall':
                if self.getDist(tile.rect.center) < 250:
                    if self.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
                        return True
```

1. Finding the distance vector between sprites and all the wall tiles is time consuming
2. I thought running `rect.colliderect()` for only tiles within 250 pixels would be faster; but clearly it's not.
3. I'm not including the source code because I'm looking for more of a conceptual answer to my problem of collision detection inefficiency.

One possible solution would be to create separate lists for different groups of tiles (i.e. wallList, groundList), however, I really believe that there is a fundamental problem with how I'm searching through the list of tile objects.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so, sorry if my question structure/lack of source code offends you.

Comment: Wow.  The code format really took a turn for the worst.  Sorry!

Comment: Add 4 spaces before code for it to be formatted correctly

Comment: @user3155622 I edited it, you can look at the source by clicking `edit` to see how to format correctly.

Comment: @Nabla I checked it out.  That was helpful, thank you.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I don't know anything about game development, but wouldn't the idea of a tile map be, that the whole map is divided in tiles with fixed coordinates, so you only have to check whether the destination tile (and its neighbours) are accessible, eliminating all loops?

Comment: I suppose there are only O(1) wall tiles (or O(n). depends what you mean by "wall" tile), as opposed to O(n^2) general tiles. So it might actually be more efficient to loop through the wall tiles only.

Comment: @Nabla The tiles are in a list and each one has a rectangle. The sprites (zombies and whatnot) move in pixel units, not tile units. So, the sprites have to check for collisions quite frequently to avoid "running over the tile" when they aren't suppose to.

Comment: @Frumples Still you only have to check tile crossings and you know the tile of the sprite's center. It can only collide with this tile or one of its neighbours (second neighbours etc, depending on sprite size). The collision check should be possible in O(1).

Comment: @EyalAr Yeah, you are probably right: There are about 1000 tiles in the map.  Maybe only 50 are wall-tiles.  I'll give it a try and post my results.

Comment: @Nabla That is a good idea. So, essentially i just check the tile indexes to the right, left, front, and rear?  I will try that as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @Frumples Take care of the sprite size. You might need to check the diagonal and second neighbours, etc., too, if sprites are larger than tiles.

Comment: There are some efficient algorithms for collision detection. A well known solution is to use a quadtree. You can find an implementation in the old [pygame wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/QuadTree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking every tile in the map for collision detection, I created a function that identifies the sprite's current tile, and then returns its eight neighboring tiles. **Tile Scan Method:**

```
def scanTiles(self):
    m = curMap.map # this is a 2d matrix filled with tile-objects 
    x = int(self.trueX) # trueX & trueY allow me to implement
    y = int(self.trueY) # a 'camera system'
    curTile = m[y // T_SIZE[1]][x // T_SIZE[0]] 
    i = curTile.index # (x, y) coordinate of tile on map

    nw = None # northwest
    n = None # north
    ne = None # northeast
    e = None # east
    se = None # southeast
    s = None # south
    sw = None # southwest
    w = None # west

    # Each if-statement uses map indices
    # to identify adjacent tiles. Ex:
    # NW  N  NE
    # W  CUR  E
    # SW  S  SE

    if i[0] > 0 and i[1] > 0:
        nw = m[i[1]-1][i[0]-1]
    if i[1] > 0:
        n = m[i[1]-1][i[0]]
    if i[0] < len(m[0])-1 and i[1] > 0:
        ne = m[i[1]-1][i[0]+1]
    if i[0] < len(m[0])-1:
        e = m[i[1]][i[0]+1]
    if i[0] < len(m[0])-1 and i[1] < len(m)-1:
        se = m[i[1]+1][i[0]+1]
    if i[1] < len(m)-1:
        s = m[i[1]+1][i[0]]
    if i[1] < len(m)-1 and i[0] > 0:
        sw = m[i[1]+1][i[0]-1]
    if i[0] > 0:
        w = m[i[1]][i[0]-1]
    return [nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w]
```

Finally, after returning the adjacent-tile list, a collide function checks each tile for collision with pygame.Rect.colliderects(). **Collision Detection Method:**

```
def collide(self, adjTiles): # adjTiles was returned from scanTiles()
    for tile in adjTiles:
        if tile:             # if a tile actually exists, it continues
            if tile.type == 'wall': # tile type can either be 'ground' or 'wall'
                if self.rect.colliderect(tile.rect1):
                    return True # if there is a collision, it returns 'True'
```

This new method has proved much more efficient and has solved my problem for now.